# ICEfaces 2.0.2 with JSF 2.1.3

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-2

i want to use latest version of ICEfaces which is 2.0.2 with latest version of JSF which is JSF 2.1.3

and i was wondering if anyone have used both of them with no problems, because i don't want to face future problems after this upgrade.

currently i am using JSF 2.0.6 with ICEfaces 2.0.2

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We too had many issues with IceFaces 2.x under Mojarra 2.0.x. Some bugs were IceFaces related and some were Mojarra related. However, we are currently giving the release candidate of **IceFaces 3** and **Mojarra 2.1.6** a chance and it looks better.